# How to use Cube.js without dependenies of AWS services

Tags: cube.js

I am using Cube.js to make graphics with mongodb. For default, the graphs are saved in localStorage of the browser, but to put in a real world, the documentation says that we have to use the aws services to persist the dashboards. Has some manner of make this without this dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Besides AWS AppSync you can use any other GraphQL server to persist your dashboard data and athenticate/authorize your users. Cube.js itself doesn't have any dependencies on dashboard data persistance and it's completely up to your frontend application on how to handle this implementation. You can use https://react-dashboard.cube.dev/authentication-and-graph-ql-api as an starting point example on how to implement this.